# trashed fonts on ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, fonts, gnome, ubuntu-16.04

Ubuntu 16.04LTS (Gnome)

I was trying to reskin an app w/ larger fonts (merging in a bunch of tts fonts that I downloaded and installed).  But somehow I absolutely trashed my system font - nothing but blank squares where characters should be - from the login prompt through the xterm content.  I can't see a thing I type and am flying blind - and pretty much am going to just redo and lay ubuntu down again from scratch, but thought to ask here - is there anything to try? (again keeping in mind that until it's fixed, I can't see what I type :( ).

Sorry for the rookie mistake and silly quesiton, but thought I'd turn to stackoverflow and see what you guys have up your sleeves to try.

/E

Answer (score 0):

As said on askubuntu forums , you can use gsettings.

It is a command line to put in your terminal.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface document-font-name 'Sans 10'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface font-name 'Ubuntu 10'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface monospace-font-name 'Ubuntu Mono 11'
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.desktop font 'Ubuntu 10'
```

- Open a terminal
- Copy paste the lines before one by one and run them
- You should have your fonts back (logout may be required)

To paste in a terminal if you cannot read the menu after a right click use the shortcut , on some terminals it is CTRL-V on some it is CTRL-SHIFT-V. or just write them if you cannot event read that message from your machine.

Long time since i used ubuntu , but without seeing anythting i think this could do the trick..

Good luck to you !

Comment: Thnanks for the suggestion, I gave it a go and my fonts are still a mess:

Comment: I crossposted on askubuntu, and will just lay down another Ubuntu image if there's nothing super easy to try.  Thanks again for the suggestion, I appreciate it.

Comment: No problem , you certainly took the right decision.. i cannot help you any further since i dropped ubuntu several years ago.. hope you'll find a solution !